# Is there a way to customize the sms message sent by Firebase phone Authentication in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase phone authentication in my app.  I am wondering how I can customize the text message sent to the user.

For example, I would like the SMS the user receives to say:
    "Welcome to XXXX App.  Your verification code is 123456."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No , you cannot customize the SMS send by `Firebase Phone Authentication`.

Go to [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) you will find this

[image]

It shows no option to customize , only you can change language.

Comment: I got message "Your Firebase App verification code is 123456", it is not the same as templates