# Firebase OTP Auth messages are differing in iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, one-time-password

I am using Firebase Phone Auth for my app in both iOS and Android. When I receive OTP message I noticed there is a difference in the received messages on both iOS and Android.

The iOS OTP Message Reads `xxxxxx is your verification code for myAppName.firebaseapp.com.` (authorised domain name).

Whereas Android OTP Message Reads `xxxxxx is your verification code.`

In the firebase console under the `Authentication` section and under `Templates` tab selecting the `SMS` reveals a different template. `%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.`

I need to show the OTP message as `xxxxxx is your verification code for My App Name.` in both iOS and Android.

I have changed the projects name and Public-facing name in project settings too. But no change in the messages.

Is this a Bug or am i missing something ?

Comment: Are you going through the reCAPTCHA flow in iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have files a bug report to the support team and got response from them. The mail response is as follows

"Is your app still in the development stage and hasn't yet in AppStore/ PlayStore? If so, this behavior of having no app name in the verification code is working as intended. It will only have an app name after your app has been published to the App/Play Store. If it's released Android / iOS app, then we do have the application name in the SMS, and we get it from the AppStore / PlayStore (and website domain for Web).

Just an additional information, there might be a delay for the APP_NAME to appear once the app is published. The update may be delayed because of the propagation between the AppStore/PlayStore update and our server picking up the changes."

As my app is in development stage i am not getting the app name in the OTP Messages. Once the Apps are published to the app store and play store this will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

There is no way for you to change the message that is sent for the OTP. See:

- [How to change the sms verification template in firebase phone auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44879218/how-to-change-the-sms-verification-template-in-firebase-phone-auth)
- [Is there a way to customize the sms message sent by Firebase phone Authentication in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158302/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-sms-message-sent-by-firebase-phone-authenticatio)

If you consider the difference a bug, you can [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I filed a bug report and got response from the support team. As per the support mail the App Name will be visible only after publishing the app to the App Store and Play Store.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Kautham Krishna's answer, for iOS, it is necessary to add the **App ID** & **Team ID** to app settings in the firebase console.